# Convert an variable sized array of doubles to wchar_t

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion

Very new to c++ but I can't wrap my head around this

I get this array of doubles and just want to make it to a 'string' with spaces inbetween

In java I would just iterate over all entries and StringBuilder.append(arr[i]).append(' ');

I don't know how to do this in c++ , best thing I came up with was this

```
wchar_t* getStuff(const double *arr, const int arr_size)
{
  std::vector<wchar_t> result(arr_size*2);

  for( int i = 0; i < arr_size*2; i++)
  {
    if ( i % 2 == 0 )
        result[i] = ?;
    else
        result[i] = L' ';
  }

  return &result[0];
}
```

I know this does not compile and contains some non-c code.

I am bit lost here since I don't know a good way to convert and what exactly here is a pointer and which is a real value.

Comment: Any reason why `wchar_t`, `char` should suffice if you are using numerals in your string.

Comment: In C++ you can't return a pointer to a local variable.  Instead, return the actual container, in this case std::vector<>, or perhaps more suitably a std::string or std::wstring.  Compiler optimisations make this efficient.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of that returning of local variables returns in undefined behaviour, just wanted to keep it short. I don't know why I have to use wchar_t, the api I am working against requires me to use wchar :D

Comment: @Nozdrum There are a number of commonly used API's requiring use of `std::wchar_t`, first coming to mind are XML parsers like e.g. Xerces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) to achieve this.

```
wchar_t* getStuff(const double *arr, const int arr_size)
{
  std::vector<wchar_t> result(arr_size*2);

  for( int i = 0; i < arr_size*2; i++)
  {
    std::wostringstream theStringRepresentation;
    theStringRepresentation << arr[i];
    // use theStringRepresentation.str() in the following code to refer to the 
    // widechar string representation of the double value from arr[i]
  }

  return &result[0];
}
```

Also note that returning a local scope variable reference is undefined behavior!

```
return &result[0]; // Don't do this!
```

Why not simply using a `std::vector<std::wstring>` instead of the `std::vector<wchar_t>`?

```
std::wstring getStuff(const double *arr, const int arr_size) {
  std::vector<std::wstring> result(arr_size*2);

  for( int i = 0; i < arr_size*2; i++)
  {
    std::wostringstream theStringRepresentation;
    theStringRepresentation << arr[i];
    // use theStringRepresentation.str() in the following code to refer to the 
    // widechar string representation of the double value from arr[i]
  }

  return result[0];
}
```

Comment: There's also `std::to_wstring`.

Comment: Couldn't you just return theStringRepresentation.str() after forming up the formatting in the stringstream?

Comment: @sj0h didn't care about the actual logic. Edit if you think you have an improvement ...

Comment: The api requires me to use wchar_t, thanks for all the answers and lovely considerations of alternatives anyways :D